# Unable to dock perspective bar on the left in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

This [page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-3.htm) says that I should be able to dock my perspective bar in Eclipse Juno on the left, just the way I've been doing it in Indigo, Helios and previous versions.

Except that the menu I get when I right-click on a perspective button in the perspective bar, only includes the following options:

- close
- show text

Has anyone else run into this -- is there something wrong with my configuration or workspace? Or is it time for me to submit a bug?

(I'm using this release: 20120614-1722 )

It seems like *this feature will be implemented* in M20120809-1200/4.2.1/Juno SR1. See
[this comment on eclipse bug 383599](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383599#c8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dock functionality is not available in Eclipse 4.2 - only in Eclipse 3.8**

See comment #3 at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383599#c3

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently in the process of enhancing the DnD for trim elements to include the Perspective Switcher (as well as tool bars and most of the rest of the trim). Hopefully this will make it into the SR1 release in September.

Note that we won't be putting the 'Dock on Left' context menu back though since we're trying to reduce the complexity by only having one way to do things...

Comment: No 'Dock on Left'? Well, if you want to have 'one way to do things', just remove 'Pin Console', Outline Minimize, etc. One way is one way - be consistent and deliver only one way of displaying views. Or yet another proposal: ask WindowBuilder Team to remove source code view. Only design tab - or no tab at all. Just one way... 

I do not think your idea of removing 'Dock on Left' is good.
For me personally this is the reason I will not use Juno - habits are part of human nature...

Comment: I have to say I agree, I don't use the dock on the right it's the very first change I make and I will constantly find it annoying and frustrating if you don't allow that to be moved. I can't imagine why you would change something like that. Completely ridiculous.  Of all the things that annoy people removing features is HIGH on the list. And that idea of making things simpler, the point of flexibility, is to make it work with the User not force the user to work with your idea of how it should work.

Comment: Eric, while I can respect your point of view, I have the following problem: my _code_ is on the right and my _packages_ and other "control" vies are on the *left*. If I want to change what I'm seeing on the *left* hand side, I have to move my mouse pointer (which is at that moment on an element in a control view on the *left*) all the way to the *upper* right. Doing this 60+ times a day  isn't taking more than 5 minutes from my workweek, but still!

Comment: Eric, also: why have the menu on the *left*, the toolbar icons start from the *left*, but have the dock on the *right*?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on the online documentation for specific information, I think large chunks of it are just copied over from previous releases into a new folder and left there.

I've been confused a few times by this fact too (in my case it was also concerning the UI configuration).

The page you supplied in your link is indeed labelled Juno (4.2) but as eugener mentioned this feature is for the 3.x (Indigo).